# Phonegap Share PLugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, share

all. 
I have trouble with PhoneGap Share Plugin.
I did all steps from instruction to use it.
Added plugin java file to the programm. Added JS, include it.
Then I created this and added event to my button.

```
  var share = new Share();
  document.querySelector("#share").addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
  share.show({
        subject: 'I like turtles',
        text: 'http://www.mndaily.com'},
        function() {alert('Share done')}, // Success function
        function() {alert('Share failed')} // Failure function
        );
  }, false);
```

Run app and it work, BUT, it work not properly. When I click on share Button, screen shadowed and nothing happens. When i click on this shadow, opened Android dialog for sharing. 
Problem in this shadow. I want that sharing dialog appear when I click on share Button.

Post screen:
[image]

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411789/android-phonegap-version-2-0-or-higher-any-update-for-share-plugin-for-facebook) is the step wise code for Share Plugin