# Android Phonegap version 2.0 or higher any update for Share plugin for facebook , twitter, message etc

Tags: android, cordova, share, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use the PhoneGap [Share plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share) for 2.0 version. I have implemented it but this is not work properly.

This plugin is written in PhoneGap 1.0 and later version any new  or updated plugin for share message on Facebook.

I've referred to this [documentation](http://tech.sarathdr.com/featured/social-share-plugin-for-android-cordova-2-2-0-email-sms-facebook-twitter-share) and this question: [How to implement facebook send, twitter share, send sms, send email in my phonegap android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218709/how-to-implement-facebook-send-twitter-share-send-sms-send-email-in-my-phoneg)

But still not getting proper solution.

Comment: You have to post some code or give more details, so people can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sharing my code which is working fine. 
Please refer [This link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share) for share plugin functionality and follow below given steps.

1- Place the JS file in the same folder of the MainActivity.java folder.

2- Place the Js file in the www folder and add it to the index.html folder.

3- Add the following line to the config.xml (if you are using new version of Phonegap) or plugins.xml (for old version of Phonegap):

4 - add html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jq_min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/share.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {

        }

        //share plugin for update status  
        function share(subject, text) { 
        window.plugins.share.show({
        subject: subject,
        text: text},
        function() {
        alert("sent success");}, // Success function
        function() {alert('Share failed')} // Failure function
         );
        };

        //Send message on facebook
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button#sendFacebook").click(function(){
        var txtsub = $("input#txtsub").attr("value");
        var txtmsg = $("#txtmsg").val();
        share(txtsub, txtmsg);
    });

    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input id="txtsub" type="text" placeholder="Enter Subject" maxlength="20" required /><br/><br/>

    <textarea placeholder="Enter Message" id="txtmsg" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea><br/>
    <button id="sendFacebook">Update Status </button>


    </body>
    </html>
```

and test this plugin for Face book,twitter,gmail etc. 
& enjoy :).

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: updated link is https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/Android please check it

you can check share plugin also 

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/Android/Share 
not sure it is working or not

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are not implementing the plugin in a proper way, just try the following steps:

1- Put the java file in the same folder of the MainActivity.java

2- Put the Js file in the www folder and add it to the index.html

3- Add the following line to the config.xml (if you are using new version of Phonegap) or plugins.xml (for old version of Phonegap):

```
<plugin name="Share" value="Path_Of_Your_Project.share.Share"/>
```

4- Just write the following into your JS file:

```
function share(subject, text) { 
  window.plugins.share.show({
    subject: subject,
    text: text},
    function() {}, // Success function
    function() {alert('Share failed')} // Failure function
  );
};
```

To Call the function:

```
$("#share_id").onClick(function(){
   share("subject", "text");
});
```

As simple as this.

Comment: thx T.baba 
I have implement same but this is goes to messaging.I want share this  message on facebook or twitter

Comment: Ah ! I got your problem,
Do you have facebook app and twitter app on your testing devices ? if not you wont see anything related to facebook or twitter.

Comment: oh ok I was checked in Emulator.Now check in device it is working fine. thank you very much now share(Facebook , twitter,Gmail etc). working proper in my device.

Comment: can u please close this question :)

Comment: just accept the answer :P but you've already accept an answer ;)

Comment: T.Baba,this works but,then how can i separate it out..for fb only fb..e-mail all mail sending options available in the phone...etc???

Comment: nope u can't separate it, this plugin will open all the intent in your mobile

Comment: just use the plugin that i put the link in the first answer

Comment: hi i get this error " E/Web Console(7559): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'onClick' at file:///android_asset/www/js/social.js:64 " how to solve this? @Imran

Comment: Have you configured plugin in proper way ?
and also make sure your phone gap version is 2.2.0 and cordova-2.2.0.js is android version JS.