# issue while sharing in facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

in my android phonegap app i have used createchooser to get all the share app from the mobile device using plugin.Its working fine to share but when i try to type in the postToWall page textbox,the facebook app automatically closed and showing error in logcat.I am facing this issue in samsung galaxy tab( android 2.2 ).

Here is my code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"www.google.com");
this.ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share:"));
```

Here is my logcat error:

```
01-23 07:08:42.865: I/dalvikvm(4054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-23 07:08:42.875: I/dalvikvm(4054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'.
```

Please kindly help me to solve this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Lets check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411789/android-phonegap-version-2-0-or-higher-any-update-for-share-plugin-for-facebook?answertab=active#tab-top
I hope you will got proper solution.

Comment: @Imran thanks for your reply.I have tried but its not working fine in android 2.2.Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

it may be as simple as needing to put http:// in front of your URL

as you may be aware, the native android facebook share only accepts a URL and nothing else. sharing text or text + URL doesnt work (a pain in the butt) - so it may think that is a string unless you put http://

example:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"http://www.google.com");
this.ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share:"));
```