# Social Share Plugin Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am using the Social Share Plugin for Cordova (https://github.com/bfcam/phonegap-ios-social-plugin), and I have everything working. What I was wondering was if there is a way to have an image you have taken or from your library shared instead of a predefined image. I already have the functions set up to take a picture and select an image from my library.

I am using this with an ImageFilter plugin here is the code for my index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- CORE -->
    <script src='js/core/cordova-1.6.0.js'></script>
    <script src='js/core/jQuery.js'></script>

    <!-- PLUGINS -->
   <script src='js/plugins/ImageFilter.js'></script>
   <script src='js/core/social.js'></script>
    
   <!-- OUR SCRIPTS -->
   <script src='js/init.js'></script>
   <script>
    window.plugins.social.available(function(avail) {
                                if (avail) {
                                // Show social widgets
                                } else {
                                // Social not supported
                                }
                                });
 </script>

    
    
 </head>
 <body onload="app.bodyLoad()">
    <div id="header"><img src="images/header.png" width="100%"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
    
        <!-- BUTTONS -->
        <div id="buttons">
            <div class="btn" id="camera" onClick="app.useCamera();">use camera</div>
            <div class="btn" id="roll" onClick="app.useRoll();">use library</div>
            <div class="btn" id="share" onClick="window.plugins.social.share('', '', 'www/images/filters/stark.png');">Share</div>
        </div>
        <!-- END BUTTONS -->
        
        <!-- IMAGE AREA -->
        <div id="imageArea">
            <!-- OUR IMAGE -->
            <div class="photo"></div>
            <!-- FILTERS -->
            <div id="filters">
                <div class="filter" id="none" onClick="filters.none(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/none.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">none</div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="sunnySide" onClick="filters.sunnySide(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/sunnySide.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">sunnySide</div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="worn" onClick="filters.worn(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/worn.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">worn</div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="vintage" onClick="filters.vintage(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/vintage.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">vintage</div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="stark" onClick="filters.stark(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/stark.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">stark</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END IMAGE AREA -->
        
        
      </div>
  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript from the image filter plugin that allows me to select an image from my library or tak a picture with the camera

```
var largeImage;

var app = {
    bodyLoad: function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.deviceReady, false);
    },
    deviceReady: function () {
        app.init();
    },
    init: function () {
    
    },
    useCamera: function () {
       navigator.camera.getPicture(app.onCameraSuccess, app.onCameraFail, {
          quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        //allowEdit : true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 910,
        targetHeight: 910,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });
},
useRoll: function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(app.onCameraSuccess, app.onCameraFail, {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 910,
        targetHeight: 910,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });
},
onCameraSuccess: function (imageURI) {
    
    largeImage = imageURI;
    $(".photo").html("<img src='" + imageURI + "'>");
    $(".photo").show();
    
},
onCameraFail: function (msg) {
    console.log("ERROR! -" + msg);
}
};

var filters = {
    none: function (imageURI) {
        plugins.ImageFilter.none(filters.rendered, {
           image: imageURI,
           save: 'false',
       });
    },
    sunnySide: function (imageURI) {
        plugins.ImageFilter.sunnySide(filters.rendered, {
            image: imageURI,
            save: 'false'
        });
    },
    worn: function (imageURI) {
        plugins.ImageFilter.worn(filters.rendered, {
            image: imageURI,
            save: 'false'
        });
    },
    vintage: function (imageURI) {
        plugins.ImageFilter.vintage(filters.rendered, {
            image: imageURI,
            save: 'false'
        });
    },
    stark: function (imageURI) {
        plugins.ImageFilter.stark(filters.rendered, {
            image: imageURI,
            save: 'false'
        });
    },
    rendered: function (msg) {
    
        $(".photo").html("<img src='" + msg + "'>");
    }
}
```

I am struggling with what parameter to use to replace 'www/image/local_image.jpg' in order for it to share the image that I have taken or selected from the library.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411789/android-phonegap-version-2-0-or-higher-any-update-for-share-plugin-for-facebook  is the step wise code for Share Plugin

Answer (score 0):

The readme file for that plugin says you can share things like this:

```
window.plugins.social.share('This is the message you want to share', 'http://someurl.com', 'www/image/local_image.jpg');
```

You should therefore be able to share any image that you have, just replace **'www/image/local_image.jpg'** with the path to the image you want to share. If you already have code to take a picture or select an image from your library, this should be trivial.

Comment: I am not sure what I need to replace 'www/image/local_image.jpg' with to get it to share the picture I have just taken or selected from the photo library.

Comment: It should just be the path to the image that you just took or selected. Take a look at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture, specifically the "Take photo and retrieve image file location" example. You'll see they take a photo and then in the onSuccess method have access to the URI of that file. This is the same URI you'd need to use. Maybe I'm not fully understanding your problem though, if you still need help could you please post the js code you are using?

Comment: I have posted the code I am using above.  Any idea of what I need to replace 'www/images/filters/stark.png' with to get the plugin to share a photo I have selected or taken?