# Social Share Cordova Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, share

I am working with the [Social Share Plugin](https://github.com/bfcam/phonegap-ios-social-plugin) and [ImageFilter Plugin](https://github.com/DrewDahlman/ImageFilter).  I have both set up and functioning.  What I am wanting to do is have a picture that I select from my photo library or take with the camera be the one that is shared instead of the predefined image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- CORE -->
<script src='js/core/cordova-1.6.0.js'></script>
<script src='js/core/jQuery.js'></script>

<!-- PLUGINS -->
<script src='js/plugins/ImageFilter.js'></script>
<script src='js/core/social.js'></script>
    
<!-- OUR SCRIPTS -->
<script src='js/init.js'></script>
<script>
    window.plugins.social.available(function(avail) {
                                if (avail) {
                                // Show social widgets
                                } else {
                                // Social not supported
                                }
                                });
    </script>

    
    
  </head>
  <body onload="app.bodyLoad()">
<div id="header"><img src="images/header.png" width="100%"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
    
        <!-- BUTTONS -->
        <div id="buttons">
            <div class="btn" id="camera" onClick="app.useCamera();">use camera</div>
            <div class="btn" id="roll" onClick="app.useRoll();">use library</div>
            <div class="btn" id="share" onClick="window.plugins.social.share('', '', 'www/images/filters/stark.png');">Share</div>
        </div>
        <!-- END BUTTONS -->
        
        <!-- IMAGE AREA -->
        <div id="imageArea">
            <!-- OUR IMAGE -->
            <div class="photo"></div>
            <!-- FILTERS -->
            <div id="filters">
                <div class="filter" id="none" onClick="filters.none(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/none.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">none</div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="sunnySide" onClick="filters.sunnySide(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/sunnySide.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">sunnySide</div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="worn" onClick="filters.worn(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/worn.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">worn</div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="vintage" onClick="filters.vintage(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/vintage.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">vintage</div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="stark" onClick="filters.stark(largeImage);">
                    <div class="filterIcon"><img src="images/filters/stark.png" height="100%"></div>
                    <div class="filterTitle">stark</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END IMAGE AREA -->
        
        
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the js file.

```
    var largeImage;

var app = {
bodyLoad: function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.deviceReady, false);
},
deviceReady: function () {
    app.init();
},
init: function () {
    
},
useCamera: function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(app.onCameraSuccess, app.onCameraFail, {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        //allowEdit : true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 910,
        targetHeight: 910,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });
},
useRoll: function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(app.onCameraSuccess, app.onCameraFail, {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 910,
        targetHeight: 910,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });
},
onCameraSuccess: function (imageURI) {
    
    largeImage = imageURI;
    $(".photo").html("<img src='" + imageURI + "'>");
    $(".photo").show();
    
},
onCameraFail: function (msg) {
    console.log("ERROR! -" + msg);
}
};

var filters = {
none: function (imageURI) {
    plugins.ImageFilter.none(filters.rendered, {
        image: imageURI,
        save: 'false',
    });
},
sunnySide: function (imageURI) {
    plugins.ImageFilter.sunnySide(filters.rendered, {
        image: imageURI,
        save: 'false'
    });
},
worn: function (imageURI) {
    plugins.ImageFilter.worn(filters.rendered, {
        image: imageURI,
        save: 'false'
    });
},
vintage: function (imageURI) {
    plugins.ImageFilter.vintage(filters.rendered, {
        image: imageURI,
        save: 'false'
    });
},
stark: function (imageURI) {
    plugins.ImageFilter.stark(filters.rendered, {
        image: imageURI,
        save: 'false'
    });
},
rendered: function (msg) {
    
    $(".photo").html("<img src='" + msg + "'>");
}
}
```

I am struggling with what parameter I need to use to replace 'www/images/filters/stark.png' to get the image that is loaded in the (div class="photo") to be the image that is shared.

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441296/social-share-plugin-cordova-phonegap/16442733#16442733 ?

Answer (score 1):

old issue, I know, but I just figured out what the problem is. It's a bug (or not implemented feature) of the social sharing pluging. Whilst it can share files with a path like this: /Users/blabla/../pic.jpg, it can't share pics from the file protocol: file:///Users/blabla/../pic.jpg.

The camera function of Phonegap uses the file protocol, hence the failure.

Now the good news: use this plugin, it's an extended version of the one you were using: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin (PhoneGap Build compatible).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this if you move `var.largeImage` inside the `app` namespace. Then you can change

`<div class="btn" id="share" onClick="window.plugins.social.share('', '', 'www/images/filters/stark.png');">Share</div>` to something like

`<div class="btn" id="share" onClick="window.plugins.social.share('', '', app.largeImage);">Share</div>`

You'll probably have to use `this.largeImage` in your JavaScript file.

Comment: Still no luck.  I have asked a bunch of different people and still haven't found a solution.  I would be happy to email you the files to look at if it would help.  My email address is brawlins4@gmail.com.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can post the files on pastebin or something and I can look at them, although I don't usually build for iOS, it seems like this is just a JavaScript problem.

Comment: When you say that I need to move var largeImage inside the app namespace.  What is the stanza for the largeImage that I would need to use in the app namespace?  I have tried a few different things with no success.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Place it inside your `var app = {....}` code, but not in any function. Then in all of those functions that use `largeImage`, you'll have to use `this.largeImage`.   But now when you are outside the JavaScript, like on the main page, you should be able to do `app.largeImage` and get the data that it contains.

Comment: Still nothing.  I have pasted the js code in pastebin.  Here is the link http://pastebin.com/fGdQ2L6B.

Comment: What version of cordova are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.6.0 for this project as a test, and then I am using version 1.9.0 in the project I will eventually release.  The plugins are set and working fine in both projects.